# How to properly traverse a DataGrid in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to be able to set the background of a DataGrid's row.

My first thought was to do this:

```
//MapDisplay is a DataGrid
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
mapDisplay.RowBackground = myBrush;
```

Now, this works but it will set the background for EVERY row in the DataGrid.
My next thought was to do this:

```
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
foreach (DataGridRow x in mapDisplay.Items)
{
    x.Background = myBrush;
}
```

However this doesn't cause any of the Rows' backgrounds to change, so I assume I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. How do I properly traverse a DataGrid's rows to set the background?

Comment: Question title and question requirement doesnt match.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged WPF, this is the winforms answer...

DataGridView rows are styled with row templates (DataGridViewCellStyle class).

Below are a stitched together snippet group of code to add rows to a grid. theGrid is the control to which we are adding rows. Event is a POCO returned from the db.

```
                var rowCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle(theMessagesGrid.DefaultCellStyle)
                {
                    BackColor = string.IsNullOrEmpty(conditions) 
                           ? theGrid.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor 
                           : theColor,
                    SelectionForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke,
                    SelectionBackColor = theGrid.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor,
                };

            var theRow = new DataGridViewRow 
                { 
                   Height = theGrid.RowTemplate.Height, 
                   DefaultCellStyle = rowCellStyle, 
                   Tag = Event.GroupName 
                };

            theRow.CreateCells(theGrid);
            var cellData = new object[theRow.Cells.Count];

            // fill out cell data
            cellData[0] = ...;
            cellData[1] = ...
            theRow.SetValues(cellData);

            // add row to grid
            try
            {
                theGrid.Rows.Add(theRow);
                if (currentMsg == Event.Pkey) theGrid.Rows[theGrid.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, @"Error Building Grid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                throw;
            }
```

WPF ought to have some sort of styling to apply to rows. Add form properties storing your row templates and then based upon conditions update the rowCellStyle.

Answer (score 0):

To change background of a particular row, requires getting that row based on some value of its `DataContext`, or its `index`.

Then apply `Trigger/DataTrigger` to your `RowStyle`.

Programmatically, you can get `DataGridRow` based on `Item` using :

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow) mapDisplay.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
```

`mapDisplay.Items` will give you list of bounded items which can be `Map objects`, or in general `Employee` objects.

, and `ContainerFromIndex() method` based on index.

And now, correction in your code,

```
   foreach (object o in mapDisplay.Items)
   {
        Map m = o as Map;
        if (m == null) break;

        if (m.AreaCode == 1234)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)mapDisplay.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(m);
            row.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
        }
    }
```